# Get e-mail from message entry section on website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I created a personal portfolio website and in the contact section of the portfolio there are name, surname, e-mail and message input box.
How can I get the message written in the message entry section as an e-mail?  Or is there a any different method?

Comment: Do you want to send the written message to email?

Comment: include code that you are working with. refer the included code to tell us where you are going wrong or getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript you can open a user's default email client with the content populated.

For example:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:" + emailTo + "?cc=" + emailCC + "&subject=" + emailSubject + "&body=" + emailBody;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_loc_href.asp